# Как вывести массив, который в массиве в базе данных MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Делаю вот такой запрос через Mongoose:

```js
async function findFunctionsInTheChat() {
    const chats = db.models.chats.findOne({ chatid: message.chatId })
    chats.find({ chatid: message.chatId }).then(res => {
        const func = res[0]
        console.log(func)
    })
}
```

Получаю это:

```js
{
    _id: new ObjectId("643beef11b195912ac16d0d8"),
    chatid: 9,
    peerid: 2000000009,
    rules: '',
    inrules: '',
    maxwarns: 2,
    new: 'false',
    functions: { all_function: 'false', ssilka_function: 'false' },
    __v: 0
}
```

Пытаюсь вывести functions:

```js
async function findFunctionsInTheChat() {
    const chats = db.models.chats.findOne({ chatid: message.chatId })
    chats.find({ chatid: message.chatId }).then(res => {
        const func = res[0].functions
        console.log(func)
    })
}
findFunctionsInTheChat()
```

Получаю:

```
    undefined
```

Поправьте что-то в коде, если я делаю не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что в файле `database.js` в модуле `chats` не было строки `functions: Object`, вот весь код кому надо:

```
chats: mongoose.model("chats",{
    chatid: Number,
    peerid: Number,
    rules: String,
    inrules: String,
    maxwarns: Number,
    new: String,
    functions: Object
})
```

Функция для вывода:

```
async function findFunctionsInTheChat() {
const chats = db.models.chats.findOne({ chatid: message.chatId})
chats.find({ chatid: message.chatId }).then(res => {
const func = res[0].functions
console.log(func)
})
}
findFunctionsInTheChat()
```

Получаем `{ all_function: 'false', ssilka_function: 'false' }`